# Changing certain on:hover colours depending on pseudo class

Tags: html, css

I have a special on-hover attribute that basically underlines whatever I hover over in a pretty looking way.

Right now the colour of the underline has been set to white, I was wondering if there would be a way to change that colour for different items?

[My Navigation Bar](https://jsfiddle.net/Jammizzle/a6qf620x/)

I have no idea what to do, I've tried changing it inline but due to it being:

```
.navbar li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 4px;
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
    transition-property: left, right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

I'm not sure it'll work inline due to this

EDIT ---

I should've mentioned that if you click the "contracts " tab, a new list appears and that I'm trying to change the colours of each of their underlines somehow, silly me!

Comment: Change the `background: white` to whatever color you need. A bit of trial and error would've given you the solution (unless I've misunderstood your question completely).

Comment: I understand that bit, but I mean changing the colour depending on the list item if you get what I mean? It's hard to explain it but in the fiddle, I'm looking to try and make the underline a different colour for each of the <li> tags, I should've mentioned that you need to click the "contracts" tag, silly me!

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to write a different selector + background rule for each `li`. Else, you should use JS. CSS can't dynamically set a different color to each element. (And I don't see any sub-menu on clicking Contracts item.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the nth-child(n) selector, like this:

```
// Override the first element in the menu to be red
.navbar li:nth-child(1):before {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, you're a star! I'll be able to accept this as the correct answer in '8' minutes! Thank you!

Comment: Oh wait! I've just ran into a complication, I really should've made this clear that's my fault. Instead of changing the first, I only wanted to change the colour of the list in the "contract" section! Click the contract tab in the JSFiddle

Comment: I've got it working now, see my answer for details. Seeing as you got me on the right path and you were first to comment. I'll mark this as the correct answer, seeing as it technically is due to my bad wording!

Answer (score 2):

Try this : nth-child() selector will solve you problem

```js
 $('.navbar ul li:nth-child(2) a').click(function() {
  $(".additional").slideToggle()
 });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #333;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
   
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

 .navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    position: relative;

}
.navbar li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 4px;
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
    transition-property: left, right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.navbar li:hover:before, navbar li:focus:before, .navbar li:active:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
    padding: 25px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
    height: 80px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.home {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px !important;
}
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right_col {
    float: right;
   width: 50%;
}
.right_col img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.left_col img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.aditional {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    display:none;
}
.aditional li {
     color:#fff;
  }
  
  .navbar li:nth-child(2):before {
    background: blue;
    }

 .navbar li:nth-child(3):before {
    background: green;
    }
 .navbar li:nth-child(4):before {
    background: red;
    }
     .navbar li:nth-child(5):before {
    background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li style="float: left"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contracts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#other">Other</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#release">Release Notes</a></li>
            <li> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.phpartnership.com">Pinnacle Health Partnership</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="aditional">
    <li><a href="#green">So this would have a Green underline</a></li>
               <li><a href="#blue">So this would have a Blue underline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#red">So this would have a Red underline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#orange">So this would have a Orange underline</a></li>
               </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Oh wait! I've just ran into a complication, I really should've made this clear that's my fault. Instead of changing the first, I only wanted to change the colour of the list in the "contract" section! Click the contract tab in the JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to Georgios for this! You got me on the right track, I created an additional selector so that it picks only the contractor ones!

This is a fiddle of the new one:

I simple had to add the:

```
.additional
```

tag in Georgios' answer

```
.navbar li:nth-child(1):before {
    background-color:red;
}
```

so it now looks like this:

```
.navbar .additional li:nth-child(3):before {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[New Nav Bar](https://jsfiddle.net/Jammizzle/a6qf620x/12/)

Comment: Great, but where attributes are involved here ?? your `href="#somecolor"` confused me . href is an attribute :) :nth-child(n) is a pseudo class . Maybe you should reword your question title, so my answer can be deleted ;)

Comment: My mistake, only started to learn CSS work yesterday! Still need to get used to the names and such!